# How to keep the 'this' context within a nested function

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I need to access my object prototype function within the inner function `oninit`. The below code does work but what I need is to have the same context as `self` within the init function so I can call the prototype function like `this.loadData`.

Please assist.

```
define([
    'require',
    'lodash-compat',
    'BaseWidget'
],
function (require, _, BaseWidget) {

    var Widget = function (options) {
        this.set('url', '/some/endpoint/url');  
        var self = this;


        _.assign(options, {
            oninit: function () {
                self.loadData.call(this);
            },
            oncomplete: function () {
                //do something here
            }
        });
        self.ractive = new BaseWidget(options);
    };

    Widget.prototype = {
        loadData: function () {
            var url = this.get('url');
            // my async request
        }
    };

    return {
        initRactiveWidget: function (options) {
            return new Widget(options);
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: You should use arrow functions.

Comment: `self.loadData()` should work just fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: @SLaks - an honourable solution, if only Internet Exploder was dead and buried :

Comment: You can also use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: You can use Arrow functions if you use a transpiler

Comment: @Bergi I cannot just call self.loadData() as I am using some widget properties within loadData() I simply want to get rid of 'self'

Comment: @Vish `loadData` can refer to the `Widget` instance through `this`. What's the problem? Or are you saying that `BaseWidget` does call `options.oninit` with a special `this` value that you need access to?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding `this` to the function directly. More on this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```
oninit: function () {
    this.loadData();
}.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are already using the variable `self`, your `loadData` will be called with the intended value of `this`:

```
oninit: function () {
    self.loadData();
}
```

Simplified example: notice that `loadData` correctly prints `this.name`:

```js
var Widget = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.name  = "Christian";

    setTimeout(function() {
        self.loadData();
    }, 500);
}

Widget.prototype = {
    loadData : function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
};

var w = new Widget();
```

Comment: Or just not use `call`  at all.

Comment: within the oninit function self and this have different context. by using call I am passing the context of oninit to access property url and self is context of the widget. What I was is to combine it together and use one context and pass the same to the prototype func.

Comment: @Vish What do you mean by "combining the two context objects"? What value does `this` have?

Comment: `self.loadData()`'s `this` will be equal to `self`. Updated answer w/ simplified example.